# Loading String Resources from A Different Path

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, c++-cx

In a Windows 8 C++ app I want to load a string resource file which is not part of the project/app package. Is this possible?

Unfortunately, this is not working: (I think I've read that `LoadPriFiles()` is not allowed for files outside the project)

```
StorageFolder^ folder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
String^ path = folder->Path + "\\Strings\\en-US\\res.resw";
task<StorageFile^>(StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(path)).then([&, this] (StorageFile^ file)
{
    Vector<IStorageFile^>^ files = ref new Vector<IStorageFile^>();
    files->Append(file);
    String^ p = files->GetAt(0)->Path;      
    Core::ResourceManager::Current->LoadPriFiles(files);
});
```

Comment: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206085.aspx) says:  "The LoadPRIFiles method accepts files only from inside the app package or dependent packages."

Comment: Can you describe precisely how this is failing?

Comment: There is an exception stating that the program couldn't navigate to the page where I tried to load the file. Call stack finally leads to the LoadPriFiles() method.

Comment: What is the content of the exception and the HResult?  Also, try wrapping the Navigate call in an exception handler, calling ToString and inspecting the result, eg:

`try { /* ... */ } catch (Exception^ ex) { String^ s = ex->ToString(); }`

Sometimes this can lead to more informative diagnostic messages.